# Is this partition algorithm correct?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I've been looking at the partition function in the book "Cracking the Coding Interview" (5e, page 119). I've copied it below:

```
int partition(int arr[], int left, int right){
    int pivot = arr[(left + right) /2 ]; // Pick pivot point
    while (left <= right) {
        // Find element on left that should be on right
        while (arr[left] < pivot) left++;
        // Find the element on right that should be on left
        while (arr[right] > pivot) right--;
        // Swap elements, and move left and right indicies
        if (left <= right) {
            swap(arr, left, right); // swaps elements
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    return left;
}
```

Given this array:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 3
```

This is how the partition worked out for me in steps

1. 4 is the pivot value. left = 0, right = 6
2. left = 3, right = 6. Swap.

   1 2 3 3 5 6 4
3. left = 4, right = 4. Exit

However, the array I ended up with:

```
1 2 3 3 5 6 4
```

Is not partitioned around 4. Have I followed the steps incorrectly or is the algorithm incorrect? I've double checked my reproduction of the algorithm and I've copied it correctly.

Also, I'm not positive why partition is returning left, is it returning the pivot?

I understand the Wikipedia implementation of partition and quicksort, but I'm trying to wrap my head around what's going on here.

Comment: Why do you say it is not partitioning around 4?  Are you expecting 4 not to move?

Comment: Well in my solution above, 5 and 6 are still to the left of 4. Doesn't that mean it hasn't partitioned?

Comment: Could you tell us what `left` and `right` indicate?

Comment: @LastStar007 left and right indicate the start and end indicies of the array. This is an in-place partition.

Comment: I see. Are you aware that this isn't actually quicksort?

Comment: @LastStar007 I understand this is not quicksort, but this is the partition step of quicksort. The partition step partitions the array so that all of the elements less than pivot are to the left of the pivot and the elements to the right of the pivot are greater than the pivot. I don't see this algorithm partitioning the array properly.

Comment: That code looks identical to the quicksort partition on the [algolist.net](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort) web site. I can verify that it does work correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The goal of the partition is to break the array into two segments.  The first segment contains elements [1,2,3,3].  All of these values are less than or equal to four.  The second segment contains elements [5,6,4].  All of these values are greater than or equal to four.

The partition function returns where the second segment begins.  In this case it starts at index 4.

Comment: But following the algorithm, I arrived at 1 2 3 3 5 6 4 and that's not partitioned around 4.

Comment: @oxuser: yes, that is the result I'm talking about.  There are two segments [1,2,3,3] and [5,6,4].  In the first segment, all the values are less than or equal to four, and in the second segment, all the values are greater than or equal to four.

Comment: @oxuser: I've revised my answer.  Perhaps it is a bit more clear.

Comment: How would you know where the second segment starts from though?

Comment: @oxuser: That is what is returned (4).

Answer (score 0):

The goal of partition algorithm is to simply take some collection of elements (for example, you work with “arrays”) and then partitioning (or splitting!) this collection around the pivot into two parts — left part and right part.

There should be some "rule" regarding the elements on the left of pivot and on the right of the pivot.
For example, all elements on the left will be smaller than the chosen pivot and all the elements on the right will be greater than the pivot.

You may also see the Implementation in the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLpH7mpwOxQ

Hope that helps!